# How does closing standard output (STDOUT) affect printf?

Tags: linux, file, unix, operating-system, stdout

If someone closes a process' `STDOUT` in its file descriptor table like so:

```c
close(STDOUT);
```

and then immediately opens a file to read/write :

```
int ​fd = open(​"myFile"​, O_RDWR);
```

and after that uses `printf`:

```c
printf("hello");
```

I know it won't go to the screen, but will it be printed in the file? If it doesn't, do you have to use `fprintf` or the `write` system call instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page of open:

**The file descriptor returned by a successful call will be the lowest-numbered file descriptor not currently open for the process.**

When you close the file descriptor for STDOUT, the subsequent open system call will assign the fd of stdout to the new file. Printf just sends to the fd it doesn't matter whether it is stdout or not. So a printf in this scenario will dump the output to "myfile"

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The function `printf` will be sending its output to the file. By default, a process's `STDOUT` (whose file descriptor is 1) is connected to the screen, however after running `close(STDOUT)` and immediately after running `open()`, you've reassigned the process's `STDOUT` to route output to the file `open()` opened, i.e., `myFile`.

The reason why this works the way it does is based on an assumption on how the operating system manages file descriptors. In UNIX systems, the OS starts looking for free file descriptors at zero. In this case, `STDOUT` will be the first available one (since it's the smallest integer in the pool of free file descriptors) and thus get assigned when `open()` is called. Any subsequent writes by the process to the standard output file descriptor with `printf()`, for example, will then be routed transparently to the newly-opened file instead of the screen.

---

Sources:

- [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/), *Chapter 05: Process API*
- [`open` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)