# what will happen calling printf after close stdout?

Tags: c, linux

I tried below code, and screen showed nothing.

```
close(STDOUT_FILENO); 
printf("Child output something\n");
```

is it just can not find the stdout,then abort the data?

I want to find wether printf write some data, since I can not print the return value so I output it to some file.

```
close(STDOUT_FILENO); 
int res = printf("output something\n");
open("./log.output", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
printf("%d", res);   // return 17
```

So printf work, but I don't know where it write to.

Comment: What was the value returned by `printf`? *Returns the number of characters printed, or a negative value if an error occurs. If format is NULL, the invalid parameter handler is invoked, as described in Parameter Validation. If execution is allowed to continue, the function returns -1 and sets errno to EINVAL. If EOF (0xFFFF) is encountered in argument, the function returns -1.*

Comment: Why do you want to close an output, and then use it? A Windows variant of your program using `close(fileno(stdout));` crashes.

Comment: What is your intent with the `open` call? It returns a file descriptor that you ignore, so you haven't written anything to the file. And it has nothing to do with standard output.

Comment: open a new file will replace the lowest file descriptor which is before belong to stdout...then I can print something that I can see.(print to stderr is also fine). So...I just want to know if I close stdout then print something to stdout,  where the data go. I found the printf return value > 0, I don' t know why printf succeed. Now I know the buffer problem.... Thanks everyone.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924455/how-does-closing-standard-output-stdout-affect-printf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this result has to do with buffering.  In general, a file which is attached to a terminal is line buffered and all other files are block buffered.  `stderr` is unbuffered.

When you close stdout, it's no longer attached to a terminal, so it's block buffered, not line buffered.  You've attempted to write fewer bytes than the buffer size (which is usually some multiple of 512), so `printf` happily copied it to the buffer and did nothing else.  If you wrote a suitable amount of data using `printf`, you'd find that it did indeed fail at that point.

You can verify a similar behavior by calling `fflush(stdout)`:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    int res = printf("output something\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", res);
    res = fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d %s\n", res, strerror(errno));
}
```

The last line will output `-1 Bad file descriptor`, which shows that the attempt to write out to stdout failed with `EBADF`, as expected.  If you need to verify that data has been written, you must call `fflush` or `fsync` as appropriate.

Note that in general, you don't want to close any of the three default file descriptors, because any time you open a new file descriptor, it will use the lowest unused number and take the place of one of the standard streams.  If a separate part of your program attempts to write to one of those streams without checking, it can write into an unexpected file, corrupting it.  The safe thing to do is redirect those streams to `/dev/null` instead.

Your `open` call for `log.output` does exactly the thing I just mentioned in that it opens file descriptor 1 (stdout) again.

Comment: That is really helpful...really appreciate. so dumb to ignore the buffering.